# Pegar o tamanho do array do firestore para usar no itemcount do ListView.builder

Tags: array, flutter, listview, dart, firestore

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var teste = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['romaneioItens']
                [index]['cliente'];
            var teste1 = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['romaneioItens']
                [index]['enderecoEntrega'];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                teste['NomeFantasia'],
              ),
              subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(teste1['logradouro'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['numero'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['bairro'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(teste1['cidade'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['UF'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['obsEnt'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está da maneira acima porém no meu itemcount quando dou um print, ele me mostra 2 - e pega o primeiro valor do array de cada doc que tenho na minha collection no caso tenho dois docs - no entanto, no meu array existem 4 itens. Como consigo pegar esse valor e passar no itemcount para que exiba corretamente os 4 itens do meu array?

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa que a quantidade de itens seja igual a quantidade do seu array armazenado no firestore você pode fazer.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {

       List<dynamic> lista = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['nomeDoArray']

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: lista.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var teste = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['romaneioItens']
                [index]['cliente'];
            var teste1 = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['romaneioItens']
                [index]['enderecoEntrega'];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                teste['NomeFantasia'],
              ),
              subtitle: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(teste1['logradouro'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['numero'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['bairro'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(teste1['cidade'] ?? ''),
                      Text(teste1['UF'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['obsEnt'] ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  ),
);
```